# Difference between two measure totals in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Using the [sample-Superstore data](https://community.tableau.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadBody/10198-102-1-13256/Sample%20-%20Superstore.xls), I am trying to do a table calculation on the row totals, Sum(Sales) -Sum(Profit). I can get the result using this formula

> TOTAL(SUM([Sales]))-TOTAL(SUM([Profit]))

But it will also show the value under Ship date 2016/2017,(I only need the total). Any ideas on how to remove the highlighted portion or an alternate way to achieve this?
[image]

Comment: You cannot hide a measure from the pane and still show it on the totals (opposite is possible :) ). If you want your result only shown at the totals you may want to change the logic and multiply one of your measures with -1 so the total will actually be a subtraction of those measures.

Comment: @HakanERDOGAN, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try one of two:
1) Try right-clicking the column where your red box is, TOTAL(SUM(SALES))... and then un-check 'show headers'. That will remove the column from your viz, however the calculations and sorting will still be there.

[image]

2) Adding the measure-names manually, rather than with the 'measure names' blue-box in the columns. Then, right click the column you wish to hide, and uncheck 'show headers'. That will remove the column from your viz, however the calculations and sorting will still be there. .

[image]

Comment: 1) No it wont, that trick only works for dimensions(eg:region). For a table calculation, it will simply remove the header

Comment: 2)  Without measure values, my data will be shown vertically instead of horizontally(side by side). Any tricks to solve that?